# How to display a list of videos from device storage

Tags: flutter

I am building an app that requires me to list videos from the device storage in a list view.

I can get the video mp4 files from path but when I put it to video controller it show error files source: NULL.

Been try many way but still fail to print in listview.
How to put the mp4 as index and print it in listview ? thank you

[image]
[image]

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
 import 'dart:io';
 import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

 void main() => runApp(MyApp());

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
           primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
      home: MyHomePage(
    title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',
     ),
     );
    }
      }

       class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
         MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


          final String title;

            @override
           _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
            }

           class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
           int _counter = 0;
           late final dirPath;
            String directory = '';
            final Directory _videoDir =
               Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.untitled/files');
                bool loading = false;

            Future<String> load_path_video() async {
            loading = true;
              final Directory? extDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

           setState(() {
           // dirPath = '${extDir?.path}';

            dirPath = _videoDir
            .listSync()
             .map((item) => item.path)
             .where((item) => item.endsWith('.mp4'))
            .toList(growable: false);
            print(dirPath);
          loading = false;
            });
          throw '';
        }

       void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
  
           _counter++;
           });
           }

       @override
        void initState() {
       // TODO: implement initState
         load_path_video();

       super.initState();
        }

     @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
         body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
          Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
           child: loading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : NetworkPlayerLifeCycle(
                '$dirPath',
                (BuildContext context, VideoPlayerController controller) =>
                    AspectRatioVideo(controller)),
         ),
        ],
        ),
       );
       }
       }

       class VideoPlayPause extends StatefulWidget {
       VideoPlayPause(this.controller);

        final VideoPlayerController controller;

      @override
      State createState() {
        return _VideoPlayPauseState();
       }
       }

     class _VideoPlayPauseState extends State<VideoPlayPause> {
         _VideoPlayPauseState() {
          listener = () {
           setState(() {});
             };
              }

      FadeAnimation imageFadeAnim =
        FadeAnimation(child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 100.0));
         late VoidCallback listener;

        VideoPlayerController get controller => widget.controller;

         @override
        void initState() {
            super.initState();
           controller.addListener(listener);
             controller.setVolume(1.0);
             controller.play();
            }

            @override
            void deactivate() {
           controller.setVolume(0.0);
            controller.removeListener(listener);
            super.deactivate();
                }

           @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           final List<Widget> children = <Widget>[
           GestureDetector(
            child: VideoPlayer(controller),
                onTap: () {
            if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
          return;
          }
            if (controller.value.isPlaying) {
             imageFadeAnim =
              FadeAnimation(child: const Icon(Icons.pause, size: 100.0));
              controller.pause();
              } else {
        imageFadeAnim =
            FadeAnimation(child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow, size: 100.0));
        controller.play();
      }
    },
  ),
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: VideoProgressIndicator(
      controller,
      allowScrubbing: true,
    ),
  ),
  Center(child: imageFadeAnim),
  Center(
      child: controller.value.isBuffering
          ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          : null),
];

return Stack(
  fit: StackFit.passthrough,
  children: children,
);
    }
    }

      class FadeAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
      FadeAnimation(
       {required this.child, this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500)});

       final Widget child;
       final Duration duration;

         @override
         _FadeAnimationState createState() => _FadeAnimationState();
           }

       class _FadeAnimationState extends State<FadeAnimation>
          with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
        late AnimationController animationController;

       @override
        void initState() {
          super.initState();
        animationController =
           AnimationController(duration: widget.duration, vsync: this);
          animationController.addListener(() {
            if (mounted) {
              setState(() {});
               }
                 });
               animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
           }

            @override
            void deactivate() {
         animationController.stop();
          super.deactivate();
           }

            @override
          void didUpdateWidget(FadeAnimation oldWidget) {
            super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
           if (oldWidget.child != widget.child) {
       animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
        } 
           }

           @override
           void dispose() {
            animationController.dispose();
            super.dispose();
                }

           @override
            Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             return animationController.isAnimating
                 ? Opacity(
                opacity: 1.0 - animationController.value,
                  child: widget.child,
              )
                : Container();
                  }
                 }

             typedef Widget VideoWidgetBuilder(
           BuildContext context, VideoPlayerController controller);

            abstract class PlayerLifeCycle extends StatefulWidget {
              PlayerLifeCycle(this.dataSource, this.childBuilder);

              final VideoWidgetBuilder childBuilder;
                  final String dataSource;
                }


             class NetworkPlayerLifeCycle extends PlayerLifeCycle {
            NetworkPlayerLifeCycle(String dataSource, VideoWidgetBuilder childBuilder)
                : super(dataSource, childBuilder);

              @override
         _NetworkPlayerLifeCycleState createState() => _NetworkPlayerLifeCycleState();
             }

       /// A widget connecting its life cycle to a [VideoPlayerController] using
      /// an asset as data source
       class AssetPlayerLifeCycle extends PlayerLifeCycle {
           AssetPlayerLifeCycle(String dataSource, VideoWidgetBuilder childBuilder)
             : super(dataSource, childBuilder);

               @override
              _AssetPlayerLifeCycleState createState() => _AssetPlayerLifeCycleState();
                }

           abstract class _PlayerLifeCycleState extends State<PlayerLifeCycle> {
             late VideoPlayerController controller;

                @override

           /// Subclasses should implement [createVideoPlayerController], which is used
           /// by this method.
           void initState() {
             super.initState();
           controller = createVideoPlayerController();
              controller.addListener(() {
              if (controller.value.hasError) {
             print(controller.value.errorDescription);
                  }
                 });
                controller.initialize();
            controller.setLooping(true);
               controller.play();
                  }

               @override
               void deactivate() {
              super.deactivate();
               } 

            @override
           void dispose() {
             controller.dispose();
           super.dispose();
              }

           @override
           Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return widget.childBuilder(context, controller);
              }

            VideoPlayerController createVideoPlayerController();
            }

             class _NetworkPlayerLifeCycleState extends _PlayerLifeCycleState {
                @override
             VideoPlayerController createVideoPlayerController() {
             return VideoPlayerController.network(widget.dataSource);
              }
              }

          class _AssetPlayerLifeCycleState extends _PlayerLifeCycleState {
            @override
          VideoPlayerController createVideoPlayerController() {
             return VideoPlayerController.asset(widget.dataSource);
            }
            }

            /// A filler card to show the video in a list of scrolling contents.
          Widget buildCard(String title) {
         return Card(
         child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
             children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
               leading: const Icon(Icons.airline_seat_flat_angled),
               title: Text(title),
                 ),
                 // TODO(jackson): Remove when deprecation is on stable branch
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              ButtonBarTheme(
                 data: ButtonBarThemeData(),
                 child: ButtonBar(
                children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
            child: const Text('BUY TICKETS'),
            onPressed: () {
              /* ... */
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('SELL TICKETS'),
            onPressed: () {
              /* ... */
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
     ),
   ],
 ),
  );
      }

    class VideoInListOfCards extends StatelessWidget {
       VideoInListOfCards(this.controller);

     final VideoPlayerController controller;

       @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
    buildCard("Item a"),
    buildCard("Item b"),
    buildCard("Item c"),
    buildCard("Item d"),
    buildCard("Item e"),
    buildCard("Item f"),
    buildCard("Item g"),
    Card(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.cake),
            title: Text("Video video"),
          ),
          Stack(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomRight +
                  const FractionalOffset(-0.1, -0.1),
              children: <Widget>[
                AspectRatioVideo(controller),
                Image.asset('assets/flutter-mark-square-64.png'),
              ]),
        ],
      ),
    ])),
    buildCard("Item h"),
    buildCard("Item i"),
    buildCard("Item j"),
    buildCard("Item k"),
    buildCard("Item l"),
  ],
);
}
}

     class AspectRatioVideo extends StatefulWidget {
     AspectRatioVideo(this.controller);

         final VideoPlayerController controller;

      @override
        AspectRatioVideoState createState() => AspectRatioVideoState();
          }

     class AspectRatioVideoState extends State<AspectRatioVideo> {
         VideoPlayerController get controller => widget.controller;
        bool initialized = false;

       VoidCallback? listener;

     @override
     void initState() {
   super.initState();
listener = () {
  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  if (initialized != controller.value.isInitialized) {
    initialized = controller.value.isInitialized;
    setState(() {});
  }
};
controller.addListener(listener!);
      }

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          if (initialized) {
    return Center(
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: VideoPlayPause(controller),
    ),
  );
} else {
  return Container();
 }
}
}
```